# how purpose string array of IDataProtectionProvider taking default value as physical path of project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-3.0

As in the below picture the Purposes string of IDataProtectionProvider is taking default values of my project physical root path. My problem is when i encrypt data from my local host and the same cannot be accessed from another machine as the key of IDataProtectionProvider is my local host path.

[image]How to disable the auto generated purpose key in IDataProtectionProvider. I found one [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.0). But when i try to decrypt the data. it saying no key found. Please help me guys.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue as OP.
In my case it was because of the default ApplicationDescriminator.

```
services
   .AddDataProtection(o => {
       o.ApplicationDiscriminator = "WhatYouWant";
   }
);
```

When I change it, the default path will be overridden.
Setting it to `""` will remove it entirely.

But it seems like a good feature to have so I would keep it.

Hope this can help people in the future.