# IDataProtector unable to decrypt when application runs as a service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, data-protection

I'm using ASP.NET Core data protection with default DI behavior. That works fine when my ASP.NET application is hosted on IIS. Now I have an application that needs to run as a service. So I'm using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices to do the windows service part with our standard

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseWindowsService()
```

The BackgroundService then hosts ASP.NET Core with your standard

```
var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
     .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
     {
         config.AddJsonFile("secrets.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
     }
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(....)
```

inside the background service, I can then resolve an instance of IDataProtectionProvider, create a protector, and use it to unprotect my secrets

```
var dataProtectionProvider = Container.Resolve<Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.IDataProtectionProvider>();
var protector = dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector(appName);
var decryptedSecret = protector.Unprocect(some secret)
```

Now that all works fine as long as I run my application from the CLI. But running it as a service (same file, same location, and of course under the same account), I get an 'invalid payload' exception when I call `Unprotect`.

I know same path and same account is important, so that's taken care of. I also know that the application can find secrets.json as I wrote some probing code that checks if the file is present and can be read before I even try to unprotect. I'm even checking if the string I'm trying to unprotect is null/empty (which it isn't).

I finally installed a debug build as a service and attached the debugger, and when I look at IDataProtectionProvider, it has a Purpose.. and when running as a service, that's `c:\windows\system32`. When my app runs from the CLI, it's the path to the exe. So, is there a way to specify the purpose on my own so things behave the same regardless of CLI/Service?

So how can I control the purpose?

Answer (score 1):

So having noted the difference in purpose of the `IDataProtectionProvider`, I was well on my way of solving this. The solution was to set a static purpose [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59050167/how-purpose-string-array-of-idataprotectionprovider-taking-default-value-as-phys)

Comment: do you mean the ***answer*** from the link is helpful? so why not upvote it? Or you mean just the ***question*** there is helpful (provided by the asker with some knowledge ...) ?