# Asp.net Core IDataProtectionProvider is different for different application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am developing an application that consists of some core components like Core, Infrastructure, MVC, and Console Application. I have the following class in my application Core library

```
public class CustomIDataProtection
    {
        private readonly IDataProtector _protector;

        public CustomIDataProtection(IDataProtectionProvider protectionProvider)
        {
            _protector = protectionProvider.CreateProtector("test123");
        }

        public string Encode(object currentObject)
        {
            var serilazedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(currentObject);
           
            var protectedData = _protector.Protect(serilazedObject);
           
            return protectedData;
        }
        public string Decode(string data)
        {
            try
            {
              
                var unprotectedData = _protector.Unprotect(data);
                var desearlizedObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(unprotectedData);
                return desearlizedObj;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
            
        }
```

I inject the above class into a **console application** and encode some data like this

**Registering Services**

```
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
 serviceCollection.AddSingleton<CustomIDataProtection>();
```

**Injecting Services**

```
private readonly CustomIDataProtection _protector;
 _protector = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<CustomIDataProtection>();
```

**Encode Data:**

```
var value = "test";
var password = _protector.Encode(value);
```

Now after encoding I save it in DB. After that, I switch to my MVC application and try decode that encoded data via console application but my decoding code fails. Gives me error

> The payload was invalid

I want to know why it's giving me an error? while I encode in a console application and decode in the same application it works fine. But when I encode in a console application and try to decode in MVC application it gives me an error.

Comment: @Alexander can you help me to understand the behavior?

Comment: In console application do you also call `CreateProtector` with `test123` parameter?

Comment: what is the code to create the `IDataProtector` on the MVC project? it should use the same application name set in your console app (which was `test123`).

Comment: @Alexander the class in my question which is CustomIDataProtection is the shared class and referenced in Console and MVC project both. So I am creating protector using the same key work which is test123

Comment: I also notice. I encrypted the text in MVC application and try to decode it in a console application and times I am receiving the same error in the Console as well. It seems if something is encrypted in MVC using Protector then can only be decrypted in the MVC application. It doesn't matter if the key is same as well

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @MaxP if you are still looking for an answer, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for answer, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59050167/how-purpose-string-array-of-idataprotectionprovider-taking-default-value-as-phys) helped me solve this. It's because `DataProtectionOptions.ApplicationDiscriminator` property will be different when you try to decrypt from a different project or application. You can find more information on that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.dataprotection.dataprotectionoptions.applicationdiscriminator?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

You can set the `ApplicationDiscriminator` property like this in your Startup or Program (based on .net version). If you set it to the same value in both project/application, it will work.

```
services.AddDataProtection(p => 
{
    p.ApplicationDiscriminator = "SetValueHere";
});
```